# Question with marketing cloud sync user -

Tags: marketing-cloud

I wanted to know below things-

1. In marketing cloud i checked that "Salesforce Integration" is connected but when i open the same user email in "Users" under Admin it is not integrated.
   What does it mean? 
   I have gone through with document it mentioned that w need to add integrated user also ?
2. if data is syn and let say i am deleting contact records from Sales Cloud and as per my understanding it should also populate in Marketing cloud (Less number of contact) but it is not updating 
   Any idea ? 
   Does hard delete also matter with Marketing Cloud sync data ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Salesforce Integration allows you to sync data from CRM to SFMC. A user level integration with a CRM system admin user enables you to utilise OOTB features like pushing email tracking data to CRM (Individual Email Results/send Analytics) assuming you are using the ContactID/PersonContactID/LeadID as your subscriberkey when sending emails in SFMC and also other features like journey builder's Sales/ Service cloud activities.
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_marketing_cloud_api_user.htm&type=5
2. If you want to stop syncing deleted contact records to SFMC, you can change your synchronization configuration for the contact object to filter by using the IsDeleted = false. (Contact builder > data sources > Synchronized tab> {choose your data source} > select contacts and when the page load on the bottom left you can edit your configuration by using All records with and choose IsDeleted = False (If you can't see the field in the drop-down it means you not syncing that field and you can edit the fields and start check the IsDeleted field to start syncing it)